# Logistic Regression Modeling & Interpretation

Tags: machine-learning, python, classification, feature-selection, logistic-regression

I'm building a logistic regression model to predict the credit risk of lending company customers.
I'm using dataset from kaggle : https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/ranadeep/credit-risk-dataset/code

**First question:**

When i'm doing EDA to gain some business insights, i found some insight using interest rate feature. But when im going through preprocessing step i found that interest rate was a redundant feature with `grade` feature. Grade actually is ordinal categorical feature ('A','B','C','D','E') and im using label encoding to make the value range from 0-6.

[image]

So to make sure which feature that i will decided to drop, im checking each feature correlation to the TARGET (`loan_status`). and found out the `grade` feature have more high correlation to the TARGET compared `int_rate` feature. And i decided to drop `int_rate` feature.

[image]

So it make me confused that i have to drop the feature that i'm using to gain good insight because it was redundant to another feature only to make better performance for machine learning. Is it irony and weird? I need suggestion in this part.

**Second question :**

I think i make a good prediction using logistic regression algorithm. This is the confussion matrix :

[image]
[image]

I also want to interpreted the feature on logistic regression that contributed the most to the independent variable using statsmodel. But the problem is i have certain features that have very high coefficient (have coefficient make odds_ratio also high).

[image]

filtered feature that have pvalue <0.05

[image]

I just think that doesnt make any sense when having very high coefficient, but on the other hand this algorithm make good prediction. So can i say that my model is wrong eventhough the performance of prediction is good? Or i can only use my model for make prediction but not good when i want to interpreted through the feature coefficient?

Answer (score 6):

For the first question, I can see that **interest rate** and **grade** have extremely high correlation of -0.95. The correlation to the target also show almost the same if you take the absolute value (both around 0.17).

You should include only **one of them** into the model. Otherwise, your model will most likely encounter **multicollinearity** problem in which two or more independent variables correlate too high to each other, which will eventually **distort** their coefficients or model output.

The question of which one you should keep is not that important because they basically contribution almost the same to the model. I suggest you use the one that is **more interpretable** (in this case, I suppose it's **interest rate**).

For the second question, you should **standardize** the features to make them follow **normal distribution** or at least **similar range** first before putting them into the model. It'll help with the high values of coefficients.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you for your response. I already use standard scaler to all my numeric features after doing train test split. I know that standard scaler not change the shape of the distribution it only make the mean = 0 & stddev 1.. So should i use log transformation first and after that use standard scaler?

Comment: Hmm if you are using Logistic Regression from sklearn, why don't you use the output from model itself (trained_model.coef_ will give you that values. Ref: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html). Furthermore, if all features are standardized and the target also just range from 0 to 1, it's really strange that one certain feature can have that too high coef of -1150. Can you double check that too?

Comment: okay I will try to double-check again. But I have another question. If I use label encoding for some feature, let's say I have 2 categorical features called X & Y. I'm using label encoding for X (ordinal categorical) and Y (binary). After using label encoding X value is from range 0-10 and Y value is binary (0 & 1). Should i standard scaler X & y features too? It make me confused because that initial features are categorical.